# Obsolete-ing Symbols in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there any way to mark a symbol as obsolete in Clojure?

I could use something like this from Lein which works well.

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/1.x/src/leiningen/core.clj#L13

But the it only emits its warning when a function is called. I'd really like the compiler to pick this up at the time code is compiled, rather than when it is called.

Of course, I could just *not* define the symbol, which the compiler would then pick 
up, but this robs me of the ability to provide any information, such as why, or when 
the symbol has been deprecated.

All of this is for a DSL where deprecation and obsolescence of terms is going to happen at a reasonable rate.

Comment: Instead of redefining the function as another function, redefine it as a macro that emits a warning while being expanded at compile time.

Comment: @Barmar Which makes it impossible to use as an argument or in a literal. Terrible idea. Instead, just force the warning during the expansion of the defdeprecated macro. (Which of course means the warning only happens during compilation of the library, which may not be what you want either).

Comment: @cubic No, that's wrong, too. The point is to warn when a client application _uses_ the obsolete function, not when the library is compiled. I think to get what's really wanted will take special support in the Clojure compiler.

Comment: @Barmar Ideally, I would like to be able to hook into at compile time. I think it needs compiler support also, and was wondering whether it was possible to do so. I guess, I could make a macro which itself expands to a defmacro, where this macro emits a warming. But this only works where the symbol is used in function position. It won't work if the symbol is being used outside calling position. Feels to me like runtime is the best I can do.

Comment: That's the point Cubic was making.

Answer (score 1):

There's already something in the comments about using macros, but as someone noted this precludes using the function as a HOF. You can get around this, although it may be that the cure isn't worse than the disease. For example, imagine your function is

```
(defn foo* [x y] (+ x y))
```

Then instead of writing

```
(defmacro foo [x y] (warn) `(foo* x y))
(foo 1 2)
(map foo [5 6] [7 8])
```

You can make the macroexpansion *return* a function, which of course can be used like any other:

```
(defmacro foo [] (warn) `foo*)
((foo) 1 2)
(map (foo) [5 6] [7 8])
```

Probably not worth the awkwardness, but does provide a way to complain whenever the deprecated feature is used while still keeping the possibility of HOF usage.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your DSL is designed. If you can design your DSL such that each form must be wrapped in a `go` or something similar call then you could write this `go` macro which does something like this:

1. `macroexpand-all` (from clojure.walk) to the passed form
2. Use `postwalk` (from clojure.walk) on the above returned form and check if any of the symbols encountered are deprecated by probably looking at some global list of deprecated symbols. You may need to do `resolve` on the symbols to get namespace qualified name of the symbol.
3. If any deprecated symbol found, the print message.
4. Return the input form as it is.

This `go` macro then can be used for other pre-processing of your DSL as this is the entry point for your DSL execution.

NOTE: You may need to come up with solution where user uses same name for his/her own symbol from one of the deprecated symbols, but again this may not be needed depends on your DSL design.